# Mnemonic for closed and exact differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

A closed form is a differential form $\alpha$ such that $d\alpha = 0$. A differential form $\beta$ is exact iff there exists a differential form $\gamma$ such that $\beta = d\gamma$.

I for the life of me cannot remember which is which. I don't use differential forms on a regular enough basis to commit these to memory. [I looked up the history of the terms, and there's an answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48491/why-are-differential-forms-called-closed-and-exact), which unfortunately does not shed light on why they are called "closed" and "exact".

One useful mnemonic I found for exact is that in the exact case ($\beta = d \gamma)$, $\beta$ is "exactly" $d\gamma$.

I would like to know other ways to remember these.

Comment: for what it's worth: 'closed' means 'without boundary', where the boundary of $\alpha$ is $d\alpha$

Comment: @user8268 I don't think that it makes sense to take the "boundary" of a differential form; "boundary" only makes sense if we're talking about a region of integration or more generally in the context of an associated homology

Comment: It might help to remember that a $1$-form is "exact" if and only if the associated "exact differential equation" has a solution

Comment: @Omnomnomnom OK, it's coboundary (dual to boundary via Stokes theorem) - I was just suggesting how to remember it

Comment: Although quite childish, I always use the following mnemonic: a closed form has $d\alpha = 0$ because $0$ is a closed loop.

Comment: Not that this helps with your memory issue, but, to make matters more confusing, the terminology changed about 60-70 years ago. For example, in Chern's papers of the 40's and 50's he said a form $\omega$ was exact when $d\omega = 0$.